# Dynamic class creation - Python

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

Here is the scenario:

I have two classes:

```
class A:
  pass:

class B:
  pass
```

Now I want to create a client, in that I need to have a small utility method, which should return my class template/object e.g: class A, class B, as I pass on the class name to that utility e.g `get_obj(classA)`.

Now, is this possible? If then please suggest an approach, as I don't get any correct answer as of now in web.

Hope I am making sense.

Comment: make the classes an [object](https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2014/06/18/improve-your-python-python-classes-and-object-oriented-programming/)

Comment: Yes, you can just have a `dict` like `cls = {'classA': A, 'classB': B}`, and then you can call `cls.get('classA')` for your `get_obj` implementation. This is a start though, but without much more details on what you are _actually_ wanting to do the actual answer can be quite different.

Comment: Why do you need it? What is an empty class, that this method would return, good for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible implementation. All the code is contained in a single '.py' file

```
class A:                                                                                            
   pass                                                                                             


class B:                                                                                            
   pass                                                                                             

# map class name to class                                                                                                    
_classes = {                                                                                        
         A.__name__: A,                                                                             
         B.__name__: B,                                                                             
}                                                                                                   

def get_obj(cname):                                                                                       
    return _classes[cname]()                                                                            

# test the function                                                                                                    
if __name__ == '__main__':                                                                          
   print get_obj('A')
```

It will produce the following output

```
<__main__.A instance at 0x1026ea950>
```

Answer (score 0):

Standard library function [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) creates and returns a class. Internally it uses `exec`. It may be an inspiration for what you need.

Source code: [https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/collections/**init**.py#L356](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/collections/__init__.py#L356)

Comment: It's funny that people are downvoting this answer considering that the designers of the language themselves seemingly have no problem using `exec` for this kind of thing.

Comment: @RickTeachey I've downvoted it, because question is not about **defining** class. Is about defining _small utility method, which should return my class template/object e.g: class A, class B, as I pass on the class name to that utility_.

Comment: I think we need more clarification from the original asker what should it really do. Whether he wants just a dict lookup like in @AnthonyKong's answer or something more dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

`globals()` returns a dictionary containing all symbols defined in the global scope of the module (including classes `A` and `B`):

*a_and_b_module.py*

```py
class A: pass
class B: pass

def get_cls(cls_name):
    return globals()[cls_name]
```

**If you are looking for simplicity**

If the code that will call this function is inside the module, then you can eliminate the function altogether and use `globals()[cls_name]` directly.

If the code that will call this function is outside the module, then you could use `getattr` function:

*a_and_b_module.py*

```py
class A: pass
class B: pass
```

*another_file.py*

```py
import a_and_b_module

cls_name = 'A'
chosen_cls = getattr(a_and_b_module, cls_name)
```

**If you are looking for complete control**

The problem with the approach above is that it could return anything defined in *a_and_b_module.py*, not restricting itself to `A` and `B`. If you want to make sure only A and B can be returned:

```py
class A: pass
class B: pass

allowed_classes = ('A', 'B')

def get_cls(cls_name):
    assert cls_name in allowed_classes
    return globals()[cls_name]
```

Note: you might also be interested in the concept of [factory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_(object-oriented_programming)).